# Servo arms (horns) for potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer

I can't find any info on this in google. Basically I am trying to find a servo arm (called servo horns) BUT for a potentiometer. They are probably named differently as the axle shaft is different.

All the servo arms I've found have teeth inside so won't work for the pot I have. My pot has a 6mm (0.25inch) D-shaped axle ("flatted shaft"). It is hall sensor but from the outside it is mechanically like a pot.

Basically I'd be just happy to know what is the name of those parts?

Here is a link to the actual pot I have:
https://uk.farnell.com/bi-technologies-tt-electronics/6127v1a50l-5/sensor-hall-0-2v-20v-to-10v-pin/dp/2319669
From there you can download technical pdf which shows exact measurements of the shaft.

Pictures:

So here are various servo arms:
https://hitecrcd.com/products/servos/servo-parts-and-accessories/servo-horns-and-hardware/product

Here it is mounted to a servo:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Micro_servo.jpg/1200px-Micro_servo.jpg

Here is how the axle of servo looks like:
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0672/9409/products/servo_75_f48aef4b-d299-49c8-9151-3b8f363ff796_1024x1024.jpg?v=1430578496

How do I mount a servo arm (or just any kind of arm) to a potentiometer with d-shaped axle like this:
https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/potentiometer.jpg

Comment: Can you add a sketch? Are you looking for a crank arm? How many degrees of rotation are you looking for?

Comment: Basically a thing like this for potentiometer: https://www.nitrohouse.com/Tekno-Alum-Clamping-Servo-Horn-25T-Spline-Futaba_p_19608.html

Comment: I recommend that you add the image into your question so that readers know what you are looking for.

Comment: why do you keep calling it a potentiometer when you know it is not one?

Comment: I did  write that reason: "It is hall sensor but from the outside it is mechanically like a pot". I was trying to simplify the problem. What kind of sensor it is doesn't change anything though.

Comment: https://imall.com/product/4pcs-lot-Diameter-2.1-2.6-3.1-4.1mm-Rudder-Arms-Landing-Gear-Steering-Arm-DIY-Accessories-For-RC-Airplanes-Parts/Toys-Hobbies-Remote-Control/aliexpress.com/32835903346/144-3253555/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found out the name of the part. Sort of. It is called d shaped 6mm flange or 6mm rigid flange or coupling or clamping hub (quarter inch and 6mm are very close). Basically anything that mouhts to a 6mm d shaped motor axle should work. It looks something like this:
https://www.servocity.com/0-770-clamping-d-hubs
I can use the outer holes as lever points. All I need to do now is to find one that has the right diameter.

For the sake of completeness here are couple of other ways I could do it.

1. buy one of these and just mount a servo arm to it:
   https://www.servocity.com/25t-futaba-set-screw-shaft-coupler
2. buy a cheap plastic servo horn and file it so it gives a tight fit to a 6mm or quarter inch D-shaped axle. Cheap and easy and because there is basically no torsion on the pot it will stay there too and not move and rotate
3. use a 6mm shaft collar and glue a plastic servo arm to it:
   [https://www.mcmaster.com/shaft-collars/shaft-collars/two-piece-shaft-collars/material~plastic/](https://www.mcmaster.com/shaft-collars/shaft-collars/two-piece-shaft-collars/material%7Eplastic/). Or drill a hole and use the shaft collar as an arm as well.
4. glue or use rubber tube to connect two axles together...

Comment: I would remove #1 since that requires a male spline to work and the collar is female. I would also advise against glue because common glues do not work well with nylon which many servo arms, as well as those collars, are made of. You would need a nylon primer and solvent. Also enlarging a hole into an accurate D-hole is not what I would call easy, but is certainly low risk and low cost so you get many attempts as long as it is a cheap horn and not an expensive aluminum one.

Comment: You can just get the  part CNC machined. Either extend the D corners out to account for the radius of the end mill or have them use a rotary broach. Or 3-D print a bunch up it if the strength does not have to be all that great.

Answer (score 1):

They don't exist. You're asking for an accessory made for a device (RC servo) made for one market that will fit onto a device (potentiometer) made for a completely different market. You will have to custom something yourself.

1. You could buy a piece of rectangular stock of plastic or metal,
   drilling or reaming (if plastic) a hole into it for your pot shaft and drilling and tapping
   a hole for a set screw. Unless you are able to machine a D-hole, in
   which case you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.
2. You could also buy a real, high quality, aluminum  servo horn with a thick hub and and drill/ream out the hole for the spline since
   the average servo spline diameter is 3mm and your pot shaft is 6mm
   which is much bigger. And if the hub has enough thickness you can
   drill and tap a hole for a set screw.
3. Buy the plainest cylindrical (i.e. flat faced, straight sided, cylindrical) knob you can find that will fit your pot shaft and drill and tap some holes into and bolt a lever to it.

You'll need a drill press for the kind of holes that need to be drilled in all this.

Comment: Surely there are arms made for potentiometers?!

Comment: @thoughtIhadaccount For who? All the industrial customers who use the potentiometer for feedback in their own products and machine the mechanics specifically to suit their installation? Virtually no manufacturer of electronic components makes things for use by individuals. Their target is industrial customers.

Comment: For who? For anybody who might need one. Maybe I am the first and only person in the world who needs one. I doubt it.

Comment: @thoughtIhadaccount That's not a good enough reason for a company to invest money into mass producing something. You're not the first to need one, but you're part of a market that is too small and sporadic for them to care about.

Comment: Keep repeating the same thing. You are not solving my problem.

Comment: You are simply assuming your solution is the only possible answer there could be. You can answer to every question with "make your own" and think you have solved a problem.

Comment: Calling me names won't solve my problem either.

Comment: @thoughtIhadaccount At this point your problem is more about you refusing to believe your part doesn't exist rather than the part not existing.

Comment: @thoughtIhadaccount Or maybe ya know...I've been down the road you are going before. Also, I never said press fit, and I did mention both metal and plastic. If you're able file plastic or able to open up a small round hole into an accurately shape D-hole with a file, then your filing skills are much better than mine.

Comment: You did very poor job looking then. I already found this: https://www.opovmedia.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=73901 and https://www.robotshop.com/en/6mm-aluminum-mounting-hub-60mm-mecanum-wheel.html. I'm done with this dialogue.

Comment: @thoughtIhadaccount Congratulations! Unfortunately, those are too big and heavy too put into an RC plane which was what I needed it for.